# Is there a TLS cipher suite with perfect forward secrecy (PFS) but without authentication, i.e. anonymous, ephemeral key exchange?

Tags: tls, perfect-secrecy, anonymity, ciphersuite

**Is there a TLS cipher suite with perfect forward secrecy (PFS) but without authentication, i.e. anonymous key exchange?**

I am not asking or wish to discuss the principle question whether an unauthenticated key exchange is something one should do and that it is prone to man-in-the-middle attacks. The question above is mostly based on theoretical curiosity.

I recently investigated the security of a mail server and had a closer look on what cipher suites the mail server supported. I noted that the server supported authenticated key exchange both with and without PFS and both over elliptic curves and traditional finite groups, i.e. the full range `DH_<ECDSA|RSA>_...`, `ECDH_<ECDSA|RSA>_...`, `DHE_<ECDSA|RSA>_...` and `ECDHE_<ECDSA|RSA>_...`. Then I noticed that the server allowed *anonymous* key exchange both over elliptic curves and traditional finite groups, but only *without* PFS, i.e. there was `ADH_...` and `AECDH_...` ("a" like anonymous), but nothing of the sort like `ADHE_...` or `AECDHE_...` (with an "e" like ephemeral).

As a cross check I ran `openssl ciphers -v -stdname 'ALL'` locally and neither found any cipher suite which looked as it was providing anonymous, but ephemeral key exchange.

Does this simply not exist or did I miss something and those cipher suites go by a different name which does not follow the taxonomy above?

Comment: Same or similar nearby: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10680/ssl-encryption-and-ssl-certificates/ https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/61340/ssl-server-certificate-optional https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50183544/creating-an-ephemeral-ssl-tls-socket-using-a-fresh-key-pair https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77604074/is-server-side-certificate-mandatory-for-ssl-connection-using-openssl https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29512394/how-to-connect-to-an-ssl-server-in-java-that-doesnt-send-a-certificate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible in TLS 1.2 and before.  (TLS 1.3 removed anonymous key exchange.)  All of the anonymous key exchanges are actually ephemeral as well, so the cipher suites you've already identified are ephemeral.

The reason that OpenSSL typically names ephemeral Diffie-Hellman with an extra `E` is because it's possible to have Diffie-Hellman certificates which contain a non-ephemeral Diffie-Hellman public key.  These are extremely uncommon and never were very popular, but they do authenticate the server, since the pre-master secret cannot be successfully computed on the server side without the corresponding private key, so the act of successfully sending Finished messages implicitly authenticates the server.  These are the `DH_` cipher suites, and the `ECDH_` ones are the elliptic curve variant.

These were created at a time when RSA was patented and cryptography was much slower and proportionally much more expensive, so the idea of doing an ephemeral key exchange on each operation was considered less desirable, and Diffie-Hellman certificates offered an approach that didn't involve the RSA patent.  However, by late 2000, the RSA patent was no longer a concern, so RSA became much more widely used (and RSA key exchange became popular for a time, and then, later, ephemeral Diffie-Hellman, both regular and elliptic curve variants, for the benefits of forward secrecy).

If you use an anonymous cipher suite, then the server doesn't present a certificate.  Thus, Diffie-Hellman (or Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman) certs aren't in use, and the key exchange is necessarily ephemeral.  It was simply not necessary to indicate this fact specially in OpenSSL, since there was little risk of confusion.  The actual RFCs specify this more explicitly within the document text.

Comment: Also note the RFC names have `anon` AFTER, i.e. OpenSSL ADH-AESblah is standard TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AESblah and OpenSSL AECDH-AESblah is standard TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AESblah .